# datePicker need to click twice to show the unavailable dates

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've created a code which disable certain dates retrieved from database.

Within getDates script I just retrieve dates from database, return them and assign them to array unavailableDates.

```
<script>
var unavailableDates;

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  
        beforeShowDay: unavailable, 
        minDate: 0,
        firstDay: 1, // rows starts on Monday
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        altField: '#date_due',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        });

    $('#datepicker').focus(function(){
        //alert($('#name').html());
         $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'getDates.php',                  
        data: "artist_id="+$('#name').html(),                       
        dataType: 'json',                     
        success: function(data)          
        {
                   unavailableDates = data;
        } 
        });
    })

});
</script>
```

It works fine but only when I click in datepicker twice. When I first click it shows all dates (no matter if they are available or not). When I click again, then it shows the unavailable dates.

Does anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, when you open the datePicker, the values aren't there yet.

Comment: Thanks adeneo. Is there a better way to do it then?

Comment: Is this a one time thing, where you disable some dates on page load, or do you have to update this everytime the datepicker is opened ?

Comment: basically when user selects an option (here they want to book artists so when user selects an artist), the unavailable dates of datepicker are updated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add async: false into your ajax call so the app will wait for the response before continuing, like so

```
$('#datepicker').focus(function(){
    //alert($('#name').html());
     $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'getDates.php',                  
    data: "artist_id="+$('#name').html(),                       
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: false,            
    success: function(data)          
    {
               unavailableDates = data;
    } 
    });
```

Another thought, you could possibly add this ajax call right into the unavailable function rather then having two things that run first, onFocus and beforeShowDay (although I'm not terribly familiar with the beforeShowDay function)

This may slow down the opening of the date picker though, as it will have to wait for the service so it depends on how fast your service is and what performance requirements you have. Other options if this can be to slow would be to pop up a "getting dates" message or pull the server every X seconds while the page it up (although that could add a lot of extra service calls...)

EDIT: After this comment...

```
"basically when user selects an option (here they want to book artists so \
when user selects an artist), the unavailable dates of datepicker are 
updated   automatically."
```

it seems like loading the list when the artist is selected would make more sense, unless your concerned about changes while the page is open. In that case I would do something like...

```
On Artist Changed
    -Disable date picker, possibly add a small note next to it / under it / 
       over it that it is loading
    -Start ajax call with async true
    -In ajax success function, re-enable the picker and remove the message.
```

This will allow the UI to stay active, allow the user to enter other information while the dates load, and if the service is fast enough, the won't even hardly know it was disabled for a second. Your dates won't be quite a "live" as the other way, but it doesn't sound like they need to be that live. You will need to recheck the dates when the form is submitted anyway.

Comment: thank you so much. I put the ajax call in the unavailable function and it works perfect.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous javascript, making it synchronous defeats the entire purpose and locks the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Because you start the request for getting the unavailable dates when the datepicker is displayed. You have to do this in advance. In the callback of the backend request you can display the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $.getJSON($url, function (data) {
         //your logic

}).success(function (data) {
        //Trigger the first click
        $('.datepicker').trigger('click');
});

$(".div_fader").on('click','.datepicker', function () {

        $(this).datepicker();

});
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer. SO exists not just to answer questions, but to help people learn. Code only answers do not help the latter.